# what's this exception?

Tags: .net, macos, exception, mono

i try to run a winaap on mac with mono.but i got this exception.
why this exception happend?

**Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for    System.Windows.Forms.Form --->    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been    thrown by the target of an invocation. --->    System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the    type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus
--->    System.DllNotFoundException: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/   Versions/1.2.6/lib/libgdiplus.dylib    at (wrapper managed-to-native)   System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup  (ulong   &,System   .Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&) at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] --- End of inner    exception stack trace --- . . .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, you're getting a `DllNotFoundException`.

Make sure that you've correctly installed the Mono Framework. It looks like there's a problem loading one of the libraries for the GDI+ subsystem.

Comment: @raha: Is this a program that *you* wrote? Or one that you downloaded from somewhere else? Are you using something that is unsupported in Mono? Not every feature is supported.

Comment: @cody:no.i knew that.i run a realy simple application that run completly with mono framework on windows before.and also i can run a consol application on mac but can't run a winapp.it make me crazy.

Comment: i think i need something like x11 or ... that is necessary to run windows form.but i don't know what?!!did you run a windows form app on mac before?

Comment: @raha: I did once, yes. But that was quite a while ago, before all of the features were completely implemented. I'm no expert on Mono, I was just reading the stack trace you provided and deducing a solution based on my experience with .NET. Perhaps someone else will come along who knows more about Mono.

Comment: @cody:ok.thanks.you are a good person.(you solved my another problem before).thanks.

Comment: @raha: What? I have no idea. You *did* ask a question here, I just don't know the exact answer.

Comment: cody:no.not here,when i want to ask a new question ,i give this issue:Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

•Sorry, we can't accept this question

Comment: actualy i underestand that  i got an exception when i use mono 2.6.7,mono2.6.8,and newer versions and mymac just works with mono 2.6.4 and older versions,what should i do?

Comment: @raha: There's been a couple of people that have encountered that issue. It's talked about [here on the Meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/why-cant-a-question-on-the-stack-exchange-sites-be-submitted).